# Laravel Relation returning null result

Tags: laravel-5

My Laravel relation is returning a null result.  Can anyone help what i am doing wrong.

Model code is :

```
public function title()
{
    $branch_id=session()->get('lbranch','0');
    return $this->hasOne('App\Accounts','code','supp_code')
        ->select('title')->where('branchid','=',$branch_id);
}
```

and Controller code is :

```
   $data = Purchase::with('title')
       ->where('purchases.branchid',$branch_id)
       ->select('purchases.*',
           DB::raw('(CASE 
                WHEN purchases.posted = "1" THEN "Posted" 
                ELSE "Unposted" 
                END) AS status'))
       ->latest()->get();
```

the queries generated are :

```
select `purchases`.*, (CASE
     WHEN purchases.posted = "1" THEN "Posted"
     ELSE "Unposted"
     END) AS status from `purchases` 
     where `purchases`.`branchid` = 22 order by `created_at` desc

select `title` from `accounts` where `branchid` = 22 and `accounts`.`code` in (100)
```

UPDATE :
If I use join, the following query is working fine :

```
$data = DB::table('purchases')
    ->where('purchases.branchid',$branch_id)
    ->where('accounts.branchid',$branch_id)
    ->leftjoin('accounts','purchases.supp_code','=','accounts.code')
    ->select('purchases.*',
        DB::raw('(CASE 
            WHEN purchases.posted = "1" THEN "Posted" 
            ELSE "Unposted" 
            END) AS status'),
        'accounts.title')
    ->latest()->get();
```

Comment: please try share the output of this query... "select `purchases`.*  where `purchases`.`branchid` = 22 order by `created_at` desc"

Comment: You seems to have issue with records... :)

Comment: There is no issue in records, because if I use join it is giving me correct result.  I have updated the post, check the join query.

Comment: Query output is :: local.INFO: [{"id":25,"refno":null,"date":"2019-05-25 22:53:00","supp_code":100,"total":"3114.00","posted":null,"branchid":22,"created_at":"2019-05-25 22:53:45","updated_at":"2019-05-25 22:53:45","status":"Unposted","title":null}]

Comment: One other thing I would like to point out.  The relation columns are not primary keys.  They are simple indexes. e.g., "purchases.supp_code" and "accounts.code" are simple indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have issue in your relationship definition. Please do confirm the Model name for the account. It should be `Account` instead of `Accounts`. But still you should confirm in your application.

```
public function title()
{
    ---
    return $this->hasOne('App\Accounts','code','supp_code')
        ---;
}
```

*Should be*

```
public function title()
{
    ---
    return $this->hasOne('App\Account','code','supp_code')
        ---;
}
```

***However I try to run your code and it working fine for me.***

Here is what I have tried.

**App\Models\Purchase.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Purchase extends Model
{
    /**
     *  get model table name.
     *  
     *  @var string
     */
    public $table = "purchases";

    public function title()
    {
        $branch_id=22;
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Account','code','supp_code')
            ->select('title')->where('branchid','=',$branch_id);
    }

}
```

**App\Models\Account.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model
{
    /**
     *  get model table name.
     *  
     *  @var string
     */
    public $table = "accounts";

}
```

**in route file.**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function(){

    $branch_id = 22;

    $data = Purchase::with('title')
    ->where('purchases.branchid',$branch_id)
    ->select('purchases.*',
        \DB::raw('(CASE 
             WHEN purchases.posted = "1" THEN "Posted" 
             ELSE "Unposted" 
             END) AS status'))
    ->latest()->get();

    dd($data->toArray());

    $data = \DB::table('purchases')
    ->where('purchases.branchid',$branch_id)
    ->where('accounts.branchid',$branch_id)
    ->leftjoin('accounts','purchases.supp_code','=','accounts.code')
    ->select('purchases.*',
        \DB::raw('(CASE 
            WHEN purchases.posted = "1" THEN "Posted" 
            ELSE "Unposted" 
            END) AS status'),
        'accounts.title')
    ->latest()->get();
    
    dd($data);
});
```

Both query working for me. And returning the desire result.

**Query1**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#436 ▼
    +"id": 6
    +"refno": 21
    +"supp_code": 100
    +"total": 41241
    +"posted": 1
    +"date": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"branchid": 22
    +"created_at": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"updated_at": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"status": "Posted"
    +"title": "test"
  }
  1 => {#438 ▼
    +"id": 3
    +"refno": null
    +"supp_code": 100
    +"total": 3114
    +"posted": null
    +"date": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"branchid": 22
    +"created_at": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"updated_at": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"status": "Unposted"
    +"title": "test"
  }
]
```

**Query2**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#436 ▼
    +"id": 3
    +"refno": null
    +"supp_code": 100
    +"total": 3114
    +"posted": null
    +"date": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"branchid": 22
    +"created_at": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"updated_at": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"status": "Unposted"
    +"title": "test"
  }
  1 => {#438 ▼
    +"id": 6
    +"refno": 21
    +"supp_code": 100
    +"total": 41241
    +"posted": 1
    +"date": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"branchid": 22
    +"created_at": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"updated_at": "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    +"status": "Posted"
    +"title": "test"
  }
]
```

**Database SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `branchid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `accounts` VALUES (3,100,'test',22,NULL,NULL),(4,2,'testsetestes',34,NULL,NULL),(5,2,'testest seat',456,NULL,NULL),(6,3,'testse aeta ',22,NULL,NULL);


CREATE TABLE `purchases` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `refno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supp_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `posted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `branchid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;



INSERT INTO `purchases` VALUES (3,NULL,100,3114,NULL,'2019-05-25 22:53:00',22,'2019-05-25 22:53:00','2019-05-25 22:53:00'),(4,23,101,4324,1,'2019-05-25 22:53:00',23,'2019-05-25 22:53:00','2019-05-25 22:53:00'),(5,22,101,32424,0,'2019-05-25 22:53:00',21,'2019-05-25 22:53:00','2019-05-25 22:53:00'),(6,21,100,41241,1,'2019-05-25 22:53:00',22,'2019-05-25 22:53:00','2019-05-25 22:53:00');
```

### **Edits:**

Tryied running your code.. here is the changes suggested.

## PurchaseController

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $branch_id = 22;


        $data = Purchase::with('account')
            ->where('purchases.branchid',$branch_id)
            ->select('purchases.*',
                \DB::raw('(CASE 
             WHEN purchases.posted = "1" THEN "Posted" 
             ELSE "Unposted" 
             END) AS status'))
            ->latest()->get();

        dd($data->toArray());

        /*$data = \DB::table('purchases')
            ->where('purchases.branchid',$branch_id)
            ->where('accounts.branchid',$branch_id)
            ->leftjoin('accounts','purchases.supp_code','=','accounts.code')
            ->select('purchases.*',
                \DB::raw('(CASE 
            WHEN purchases.posted = "1" THEN "Posted" 
            ELSE "Unposted" 
            END) AS status'),
                'accounts.title')
            ->latest()->get();

        dd($data);*/
    }
```

Purchage Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Purchase extends Model
{
    //
    public $table = "purchases";

    public function account()
    {
        $branch_id=22;

        return $this->hasOne('App\Account','code','supp_code')
            ->where('branchid', $branch_id);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:11 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "refno" => 24
    "supp_code" => 100
    "total" => 3114
    "posted" => null
    "date" => "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    "branchid" => 22
    "created_at" => "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    "updated_at" => "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    "status" => "Unposted"
    "account" => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "code" => 100
      "title" => "test"
      "branchid" => 22
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:11 [▼
    "id" => 6
    "refno" => 21
    "supp_code" => 100
    "total" => 41241
    "posted" => 1
    "date" => "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    "branchid" => 22
    "created_at" => "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    "updated_at" => "2019-05-25 22:53:00"
    "status" => "Posted"
    "account" => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "code" => 100
      "title" => "test"
      "branchid" => 22
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts.  My Accounts model is named 'Accounts'.  I even changed it to Account, but still I am getting null result for the title column.  Rest everything is same as you mentioned.  I think I have to use the Join query for this.  Thanks alot.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed for me it's working fine...can you try the solution / step I mentioned.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed please mark this if it helps to prepare your solution.

Comment: Its still giving me null value in title column.  I created a fresh Laravel 5.8 project and copy pasted the code you provided with some minor changes.  Tested it with my current database, did'nt work.  Then I created a new database using your queries, still not working.  Here is a google drive link for the whole project : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vmj64uoxxEGmbAmprJrFQFEGt0Kuvr9B/view?usp=sharing   I am using this link to check "localhost:8000/purchase"

Comment: PurchaseController > $branch_id = 22;


        $data = Purchase::with('account')
            ->where('purchases.branchid',$branch_id)
            ->select('purchases.*',
                \DB::raw('(CASE 
             WHEN purchases.posted = "1" THEN "Posted" 
             ELSE "Unposted" 
             END) AS status'))
            ->latest()->get();

        dd($data->toArray());

Comment: Purchase Model > public function account()
    {
        $branch_id=22;

        return $this->hasOne('App\Account','code','supp_code')
            ->where('branchid', $branch_id);
    }

Comment: Remove `->select();`  From the relationship definition ( purchase > hasone block) and everything must work perfactly.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed changes updated in answer as well.. check the edit block `Edits:`

Comment: Yes now its working.  Thanks.  But it is returning all columns from accounts table as an array, I needed only 'title' column.

Comment: You are welcome! try use single one and could exclude other one as per your requirement.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your time and efforts.